# interface as a reference variable

Tags: java, class, interface

```
interface abc
{
   ...
}
```

Suppose I have  methods which have a return type of Object and interface type `abc`.

```
class xyz
    {

    Object meth ()
    {
        ... 
    }

    abc meth2()
    {
        ...
    }

    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        xyz x = new xyz() ;

        Object a = x.meth() ;

        abc c = x.meth2() ;
    }
}
```

I don't want to implement the interface abc .
The reference variable c is of type abc but what is the object type for c ?
We cannot create objects of an interface , so what it could possibly be ?

For example :
sup s = new sub() ; // where sub is subclass of sup . Here sup is the return type and sub is the object type .

Comment: How do you plan to implement the method `meth2` without creating an object of `abc` unless you return `null`? In the latter case, the value of `c` will be `null`.

Comment: Please stick to Java naming conventions (like `Abc` for a type) and ident your code

Comment: If you want an object of type `abc`, you _must_ define a class that implements it (although it could be an anonymous class).  I'm not clear on how you thought you could do anything useful without implementing the interface.

Comment: I am facing a similar trouble to understand the getAnnotations() method which has a return type of Annotation[] and Annotation is an interface .

Comment: There's a class somewhere that implements `Annotation` (maybe more than one such class).  It might be a private class buried somewhere in the Java runtime library.

Comment: You cannot implement method `meth2` without creating object of type `abc`!

Comment: P.S. I'd avoid using `meth` as an abbreviation for "method" because it has another meaning.

Comment: @ajb the source code of getAnnotations() is not much helpful .

Comment: It seems to refer to a Sun package whose source isn't part of the standard source distribution.  That's beside the point.  Somewhere, there is Java code that defines a class that implements `Annotation`.  You don't need to know what it is--only that there is a class and that this class implements the methods defined by `Annotation` (i.e. `annotationType`).  So what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying type of `c` can be anything that implements `abc`. The actual type depends on your implementation of `meth2`.

"But in my code, nothing implements `abc` though!" you said. If nothing implements `abc`, `meth2` cannot be implemented. It can never return a correct value because it can't create a type that is compatible with `abc`, if no types implement `abc`.

However, in `meth2`, you can create what is called an "anonymous class":

```
return new abc() {
    // all the methods required by abc will be put here...
};
```

During compilation, this anonymous class will be turned into an inner class of the enclosing class that implements `abc`, and it will have the fully qualified name of something like `yourpackage.EnclosingClass$1`

Answer (score 0):

In order to answer your question you must first think about the possible ways to write the `meth2()`. You must need to implement the ABC interface somewhere. You can do something like this:

```
ABC meth2() {

    return new ABC(){
         // Implement the methods that are defined in ABC interface
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `meth2` can only return `null` or an instance of a class implementing the interface `abc`.